# Team Fortress 2 - Multiplayer works perfectly but Singleplayer is very glitchy. (Video Included)

Tags: team-fortress-2, source-engine

When playing multiplayer I have no issues, but when I play singleplayer via 'Create Server' I get graphical and physics glitches. I made a video to demonstrate, because it's hard to explain well.

I am using the Chris Config and the BroeselHUD.

Comment: And if you run game without this config and HUD mod? Have you checked?

Comment: please try to verify the gamecache. go into your steam library and rightclick tf2-> properties -> local files -> verify integrity of game cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solid chance either 1) A game file is corrupted; or 2) One of your mods is interfering with listen servers.

- Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf. Take the entire contents of your custom folder + cfg folder and move both to your desktop.
- Open Steam, right click on TF2 > Properties > Local Files > Verify Integrity of Steam Cache.
- Once complete, launch the game and see if you have any issues with your listen server. If you still have issues, it may be a good idea to delete and reinstall TF2. If there are no issues, start adding back in your mods and custom script files a few at a time, launching the game and testing for issues with each time you re-add something.

You'll probably want to add the less intrusive mods back in first, such as model or material replacements, as those are less likely to mess with the overall game.